# Can anyone help me debug my program

Tags: python

I'm in a beginning programming class and our program is to create a program to gather information on four different zip codes and five different types of coffee drinks to see if our friend should open up a coffee shop in that area.
My program will not accept my variables
My other problem with my program is it won't loop back around to get more input. I tried to reset the user answer to allow it to go back to the beginning but it doesn't read it.

I set up an accumulater for my if statement 
Example

```
while UserAnswer == "yes":
    ZipCode = input("Enter Zip Code:  ")
    print("Here are your menu choices: \n m = Cafe Mocha\n l = Cafe Latte ")
    print(" r = Cafe Regular \n d = Cafe Regular Decafe \n c = Cafe Carmel")
    CoffeeType = input("Enter your order: ")
    Quantity = input("Enter quantity: ")
    #Start inner loop with if statements to determine the quantity of the coffee
    while UserAnswer == "no"
        if ZipCode == 48026:
           if CoffeeType == "m":
               CM48026 = Quanity + CM48026'
```

My accumulater CM48026 doesn't save and at the end it prints out 0.

Comment: You have a scope issue.  `CM48026` is defined in the innermost if block and will not be bound/defined once that inner block ends.  Try defining it outside of your while loop (set it to `None` initially if you'd like) and see what happens.

Comment: `while UserAnswer == "no"` needs a colon afterwards

Comment: Style tip: variable names should be lowercase in Python and use `snake_case` rather than `CamelCase`.  Reference: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an initial value for the accumulator. And that should be done outside the inner loop. Because you are using the same variable in the expression which provides the value for the accumulator.

So, doing `a = b + a` will not really work, as the value of a at the right is not really defined.

Moreover, there's a typo for the variable **quantity**, and that might *actually* be the reason why your code is not working!